# Filters in Electron's showOpenDialog only returning first object in the array

Tags: javascript, electron

```
const getFile = () => {
  const files = dialog.showOpenDialog({
    properties: ['openFile'],
    filters: [
      { name: 'Markdown', extensions: ['md', 'mdown', 'markdown'] },
      { name: 'Text', extensions: ['txt', 'text'] },
    ],
  });
```

For my filters the app only uses the first object as a correct filter.  For example when markdown is listed first I can only select markdown files and when the text object is listed first I can only select text files.  Based on the docs I should be able to create filters as so

```
{
  filters: [
    { name: 'Images', extensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'] },
    { name: 'Movies', extensions: ['mkv', 'avi', 'mp4'] },
    { name: 'Custom File Type', extensions: ['as'] },
    { name: 'All Files', extensions: ['*'] }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

Electron dialog filter object takes the filters as an array of filter object with file extension array. When we add multiple filter object then it shows like the list of the filter with a defined filter object name. As simple dropdown binds.

For example -

**Example 1 -** When we use below filter object "filters" then -

```
const openDialogOptions: OpenDialogOptions = {
      defaultPath: '',
      filters: [
        { name: "All Files", extensions: ["*"] },
        { name: 'Word Template', extensions: ["dot", "dotx"] },
        { name: 'Word Document', extensions: ["doc", "docx"] },
        { name: 'MS Perfect', extensions: ["wpt"] }],
      properties: ['openFile']
    }
```

it binds the list of the filter in the dropdown as below -

[image]

**Example 2 -** When we use below filter object "filters" then -

```
const openDialogOptions: OpenDialogOptions = {
      defaultPath: '',
      filters: [
        { name: 'Word Template', extensions: ["doc", "docx","dot", "dotx"] },
        { name: 'MS Perfect', extensions: ["wpt"] }],
      properties: ['openFile']
    }
```

it binds the list of the filter in the dropdown as below -

[image]

Comment: I still don't see the difference between your two examples.

In my example only the first item in the array is shown in the dropdown menu.